# "Came to me dim" vs "came dim to me"

Tags: meaning, grammar, adjectives, word-order

"The light of hope came to me dim." I found this sentence in *The story of my life* by Helen Keller.

Why does the adjective "dim" come after the pronoun "me", not after the verb "came" (such as "The light of hope came dim to me")? I am confused. Please get this easier for me.

Comment: I found this sentence in "The story of my life by Helen Keller"

Answer (score 1):

It's a stylistic choice where to put the adjective *dim*, not a grammatical one. In other words, the adjective (dim) complements the subject (light of hope) describing the state of the subject (light of hope) and it doesn't matter where it is placed. In English, you usually place a more important word or phrase before a less important one. For example:

> The light of hope **came to me** and it was dim. --> The light of hope **came to me** dim.

vs

> The light of hope **came dim** and it came to me --> The light of hope **came dim** to me.

Both of them are perfectly grammatical and there is nothing wrong with the second sentence. In other words, it is a matter of where to place "to me" rather than where to place "dim" as the sentence "The light came dim." is perfectly grammatical and idiomatic. You can compare the following sentences:

> I came very late to the meeting

vs

> I came to the meeting very late.

They both mean basically the same thing.

However,

> I came home late.

vs

> I came late home.

the former sounds far more idiomatic than the latter because not many people use the latter. I wouldn't say the adjective "dim" comes after the pronoun *me*, but it comes after the (verbal) phrase *came to me*. You can usually split the (verbal) phrase and insert an adjective, but not in some idiomatic expressions.

Comment: The OP doesn't ask about this, but I think that your answer would be more useful to readers if it addressed the question of how (if at all)  "The light of hope came to me dim" differs in meaning from "The light of hope came to me dimly."